# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, runtime-error, helper

Hi i've compile this java project. This is my first project of hello world but when i try to run it on cmd i have this error. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
public class CiaoMondo { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

This is the error:
[image: x]

Comment: don't use links to show code/errors. copy the code into to the question

Comment: Ops sorry. I've copied the error also, can you help?

Comment: shows us your code, i don't see the code in the question

Comment: public class CiaoMondo { public static void main(String[] args) { // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window. System.out.println("Hello, World"); } } 


-----------------------------
The code is a simply hello world, into my eclipse console when i run it, it run perfectlly, but when i open cmd and after the compiling with the javac command i have the error

Answer (score 0):

A ClassNotFoundException can be caused for several reasons. The most common (in my experience) are because the `java ClassName` command is blocked by your firewall, or the file your class is in is improperly named.

Comment: My project name is primoprogramma  and the only class name is CiaoMondo. I don't recognize the error :( .
Then i run javac CiaoMondo.java  and  java CiaoMondo. But then i've the error

Comment: Does it tell you that CiaoMondo is the missing class, or is it a different one? Most java code needs some kind of import (usually java.io.* for basic console applications)

Comment: Into the image i linked it says in the end of the error CiaoMondo (wrong name) but the name is that mmh...

Comment: In the image you linked, you seem to have a typo -- you did not capitalize "mondo" in CiaoMondo (typed command was "java primoprogrammajava.Ciaomondo" instead of "java primoprogrammajava.CiaoMondo"). Could this be your error?